# Visual Studio and Umbraco setup through Remote Control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, umbraco, remote-access, small-business-server

I'm new to umbraco and have recently downloaded visual studio with the objective of setting it all up and getting it all to work. However, fact remains that I'm not suceeding and I've not been able to find any post related to this topic on the internet.

The scenario is simple:

---

I connect to a Windows Small Business Server through a gateway as: remote.mysite.com.

In that connection I log on to another server where I finally find the root directory of the umbraco installation.

---

How would I synchronize Visual Studio with that Umbraco folder, so I don't have to transfer files all the time?

Any help would be appreciated much!

Best regards,

Brinck10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to do an XCOPY deployment of your code to that distant server, Visual Studio will need to have a network connection.

- You could [set up an SSTP VPN connection](http://blog.c7solutions.com/2009/03/configuring-sstp-vpn-on-small-business_31.aspx) through your Small Business Server and connect to the Umbraco server
- You could also set up an FTP server on your Umbraco server but you'd need to also make exceptions on your office firewall.
- You can also [watch this video](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx) by Scott Hanselman.